# Show the popup basis on what option I am selecting

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a popup basis on what value I am selecting using HTML and Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <select id="mysel">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input#mysel').live('change',function(){
    var sel_opt = $(this).val();
    alert(sel_opt);
    if(sel_opt==1)
    {
        alert()
    }
     else if(sel_opt==2)
     {
        alert()
     }
      else if(sel_opt==3)
      {
        alert()
      }

    });

 });
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But the above code is not working somehow. Any idea what is the problem?

**Updated Code:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
 <select id="mysel">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mysel').on('change', function(){
        var sel_opt = $(this).val();
        alert(sel_opt);

        if(sel_opt==1)
        {
            alert()
        } 
        else if(sel_opt==2)
        {
            alert()
        }
        else if(sel_opt==3)
        {
            alert()
        }

    });
});

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code is still not working after adding the jQuery library as well. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably because you didn't include the jQuery library anywhere...specifically before any code that uses it. As well as a `<head>`. And `live` was deprecated in 1.7, removed in 1.9

Comment: Your code is fine by adding older version of jQuery as @Ian mentioned.  If I'm wrong add a jsfiddle to your code.

Comment: You could try replacing `live` which is deprecated/removed (thanks @Ian) with either `bind` or `on` and it will work.

Comment: You need to have the closing `</script>` tag next on your jQuery include. I would also put that in the `<head>` section of the HTML too.

Comment: so on the line that you include jQuery, you need to close that tag `</script>`. Then where your javascript is you need to open another `<script type="text/javascript">`, then after your code keep the closing `</script>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery 1.7+ the live function has been deprecated and was actually entirely removed in 1.9. Try replacing `live` with either `bind` or `on`, and it should do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mysel').on('change', function(){
        var sel_opt = $(this).val();
        alert(sel_opt);

        if(sel_opt==1)
        {
            alert()
        } 
        else if(sel_opt==2)
        {
            alert()
        }
        else if(sel_opt==3)
        {
            alert()
        }

    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6NykM/

Comment: Can you provide me exact jquery library that I need to put in my head?

Comment: The closing `</script>` tag is required in your jQuery include.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you include the jQuery library in your html head. Tested and works with old variants of jQuery (1.6.4 ~ 1.8.3 on jsFiddle).

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MbmTF/

Comment: Can you provide me exact jquery library that I need to put in my head?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Jquery librabry will solve your issue 
The Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/Nz4Vg/)

```
$(':input#mysel').live('change',function(){
var sel_opt = $(this).val();
alert(sel_opt);
if(sel_opt==1)
{
    alert("It's one");
}
 else if(sel_opt==2)
 {
    alert("It's two");
 }
  else if(sel_opt==3)
  {
    alert("It's three");
  }

});
```

Comment: Can you provide me exact jquery library that I need to put in my head?

Comment: In my Js fiddle you can get the JQuery in External Resources Tab [Left side of the page] i'm using jquery-1.8.2.min.js

Comment: I just made that change. Now see my update in the question and still it is not working. Is there anything I am missing again?

Comment: when including jquery library you forgot to close </script> tag and then again wrap your Javacsript code in <script></script> tag it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine script including line and script code in one tag.You need to change like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mysel').on('change', function(){
        var sel_opt = $(this).val();
        alert(sel_opt);

        if(sel_opt==1)
        {
            alert()
        } 
        else if(sel_opt==2)
        {
            alert()
        }
        else if(sel_opt==3)
        {
            alert()
        }

    });
});

 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

try using switch statement instead of if/else loop for better readability.

the trouble you have is with data type, the obtained type is string and you are comparing int.

```
 $('#mysel').on('change',function(){
    var sel_opt = $(this).val();
    alert(sel_opt);

switch(sel_opt){
case "1":
alert();
break;
case "2":
alert();
break;
case "3":
alert();
break;
}
    });
```

check the fiddle for this..
http://jsfiddle.net/S9jkK/1/